# Wordpress post content with shortcodes to be converted into plain HTML

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-shortcode

A Wordpress eLearning website developed using LearnDash.
Need to use post content outside wordpress but the content has shortcodes.

How do I just convert the shortcode into HTML code using PHP and wordpress functions.
Below is the sample content :

```
[vc_row padding_top="0px" padding_bottom="0px" bg_video="" class="" style=""][vc_column fade_animation_offset="45px" width="1/1"][image src="942" alt="" href="" title="" info_content="" lightbox_caption="" id="" class="" style=""][gap size="1.313em" id="" class="" style=""]
```

When I visit the webpage, it gets converted into HTML. But I want the HTML content only for the above content to display in a mobile app. I don't want to download the complete HTML page.

Comment: If the shortcode is not rendering for your mobile app, does that mean your are getting your content using wp-json API?

Comment: yes. I am using wordpress rest API to get the content.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the docs for [`do_shortcode()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/).

As long as you have the Wordpress core included you can run it like so:

```
echo do_shortcode('[some_shortcode]');
```

Comment: It will run the shortcode as normal, if that shortcode generates HTML then yes it will return HTML.

Comment: It worked with images. But there are certain shortcodes which are not getting converted into HTML.



[vc_icon icon_fontawesome="fa fa-check" color="mulled_wine" background_style="rounded-outline" background_color="mulled_wine" size="lg" align="center"]

Answer (score 0):

The REST API does not render shortcodes, so you have to force it.  Create a file wp-content/mu-plugins/render-xyz-shortcodes.php.  You might have to create the mu-plugin for since it's not there by default.

```
<?php

/**
* Render the shortcode in wp-json API
*/

add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_field(
        'post',
        'content',
        array(
            'get_callback'    => 'render_xyz_do_shortcode',
            'update_callback' => null,
            'schema'          => null,
        )
    );

    register_rest_field(
        'post',
        'excerpt',
        array(
            'get_callback'    => 'render_xyz_do_shortcode',
            'update_callback' => null,
            'schema'          => null,
        )
    );
});

function render_xyz_do_shortcode( $object, $field_name, $request ) {

    global $post;
    $post = get_post($object['id']);

    $output = array();

    //Apply the_content's filter, one of them interpret shortcodes
    switch( $field_name ) {
        case 'content':
            $output['rendered'] =  apply_filters( 'the_content', $post->post_content );
            break;
        case 'excerpt':
            $output['rendered'] =  apply_filters( 'the_excerpt', $post->post_excerpt );
            break;
    }

    $output['protected'] = false;

    return $output;
}
```